# como esconder la tabla en mi reporte de odoo

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo, wizard

ya pude mostrar la información del popup que cree en odoo lo que estoy intentando ahora es esconder la tabla en el reporte ya que en este mismo muestra ambas tablas tanto la tabla general como la tabla de la seleccion que se haya echo ya sea por empleado o destino estuve intentando con la propiedad attrs pero no funciona

Adjunto codigo xml de los reportes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="sales_general_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
       <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
           <h3 class="text-center">Sales General Report
               <span style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>From</strong>:<t t-esc="from_date"/> <strong>To</strong>: <t t-esc="to_date"/></span>
           </h3>
           <div class="article mt0 o_report_layout_standard">
               <t t-if="type == 'General'">
                     <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="width:30%">Date</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Seguro</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Vencimineto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                       </thead>
                        <t t-foreach="form" t-as="order">
                         <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="order['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['country']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['invoice']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['validity']"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['seller']"/></td>
                          </tr>
                        </t>
                    </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if="type == 'Executive'" attrs="{'invisible': [('seller_id', '=', '[]')]}">
                   <h3>
                       <span style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>Ejecutivo</strong>:<t t-esc="employee"/></span>
                   </h3>
                 <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                     <thead>
                       <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                     </thead>

                      <t t-foreach="form" t-as="seller">
                        <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="seller['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['country']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['invoice']"/></td>
                        </tr>
                      </t>
                  </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if="type == 'Executive' and seller_id == []">
                   <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="width:30%">Date</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Seguro</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Vencimineto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                       </thead>
                        <t t-foreach="form" t-as="seller">
                         <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="seller['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['country']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['invoice']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['validity']"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['seller']"/></td>
                          </tr>
                        </t>
                    </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if=" type == 'Country'" attrs="{'invisible': [('country_arrival', '=', '[]')]}">
                    <h3>
                           <span style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>Destino</strong>:<t t-esc="country"/></span>
                    </h3>
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                   </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="form" t-as="country">
                       <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="country['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['invoice']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['seller']"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </t>
               </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if="type == 'Country' and country_arrival == []">
                   <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="width:30%">Date</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Seguro</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Vencimineto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                       </thead>
                        <t t-foreach="form" t-as="country">
                         <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="country['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['country']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['invoice']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['validity']"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['seller']"/></td>
                          </tr>
                        </t>
                    </table>
               </t>
           </div>
           <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                           <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="page"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="topage"/>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </t>
</template>
```

asi es como tengo la estructura del reporte e imprime l atabla dependiendo la seleccion que yo haga ya sea general o por empleado o por destino o poe estas dos ultimas pero dejando sus campis vacion osea no eligiendo ningun empleado o destino y le finalidad es que si esos dos campos quedan vacios en el reporte muestre el epreorte general pero me muestra ambas tablas

Adjunto imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es como muestra todos los reportes hice una prueba con general haber si pasaba lo mismo y si pasa no se si este mal la estructura del reporte o este mal como haya puesto el modelo que puedo hacer aqui para resolverlo